# XML with XSL shows blank page in Chrome and Edge browsers

Tags: xml, xslt

When I use XML with xsl stylesheet, Chrome, Edge shows blank page. When I remove the stylesheet information from the XML file, the data is shown in tree structure.

What setting do I need to change in Chrome so that when I double click on XML file, it shows the data formatted.

Note: XML and XSL are in the same folder.

**My XML File**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="people.xsl"?>
<people>
    <husband employed="Yes">
        <name>Mark</name>
        <age>45</age>
        <wife>
            <wname>Janet</wname>
            <age>29</age>
        </wife>
    </husband>
    <husband employed="No">
        <name>Matt</name>
        <age>42</age>
        <wife>
            <wname>Annie</wname>
            <age>41</age>
        </wife>
    </husband>
</people>
```

**My XSL file**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="husband">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have installed Firefox also but it shows unformatted data.

**Chrome Version :** Version 122.0.6261.112 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Microsoft Edge Version:** Version 122.0.2365.80 (Official build) (64-bit)

**Firefox Version:** 123.0.1 (64-bit)

I am on Windows 10 Pro

Comment: How are you running this? As an XSLT? Running it on [XSLT Test Tool](https://xslttest.appspot.com/) gives "Mark" and "Matt", which is correct. The problem is not with your code (that seems like a learning exercise) but with the way you're running it.

Comment: Yes its a learning exercise. I am double clicking the xml file which opens on chrome. That  is how I am running it. I saw that in most of the tutorials on Youtube.